# Get column number from column name

Tags: handsontable

Is there any method to get the column number from the column name?

I can only retrieve the column name, and I need the column number for getCellMeta.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more context to your question? Why do you need to get a column number using the name? When and why do you need getCellMeta?

Comment: Because I could only retrieve the col name. I need getcellmeta for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721500/custom-renderer-function-not-working-in-handsontable-plugin

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to reinvent the wheel a bit here. Handsontable already has some of the functionality you are after. Have a look at my answer to the post you referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made this function that solved my problem:

```
function GetColFromName(name)
{
    var n_cols  =   $editorTableContainer.handsontable('countCols');
    var i       =   1;     

    for (i=1; i<=n_cols; i++)
    {
        if (name.toLowerCase() == $editorTableContainer.handsontable('getColHeader', i).toLowerCase()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //return -1 if nothing can be found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost what I required but not quite as I needed the column prop.  I couldn't find the answer anywhere so thought I would add this to the thread that helped me.

instead of using 'getColHeader' use 'colToProp'.

Answer (score 2):

Use `propToCol("Column Name")`. This returns the column's index.