# Custom renderer function not working in handsontable plugin

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a function that handles some `onChange` events and works well. That function calls another one to check for the contents of the cell, and if there is something wrong it should change the cell color.

```
function Check(x, y)
{
    var content =   $editorTableContainer.handsontable('getDataAtCell', y, x);
    var split   =   content.split(' ');    

    $.each(split, function (key, value) {
        $.get('check.php?word=' + value, function (data) {
            //blank if no error otherwise it returns an array of suggestions (only need to check if there is an error)
            if (data) {
                alert("test");
                var meta = $editorTableContainer.handsontable('getCellMeta', y, x);
                meta.renderer = ErrorRenderer;
            }
        });
    });

    return;
}
```

And here is my simple ErrorRenderer:

```
function ErrorRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties)
{
  Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log(row);
  td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  td.style.color = 'green';
  td.style.background = '#CEC';
}
```

The ErrorRenderer is never called, eventhough the alert is triggered, any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: off-topic: fwiw, there's a useful JS code convention to reserve capitalized function names for constructor functions only. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of that

Comment: See my comment about rendering in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using handsontable, why don't you use its built in functionality?

Have a look at HTs [conditional formatting](http://handsontable.com/demo/conditional.html)

Also, in version 0.9.5 a column option was added `validator`. Details [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Options).

```
validator (value: Mixed, callback: Function)
```

or

```
validator : RegExp Object
```

Then using the event (details [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events)):

```
afterValidate (isValid: Boolean, value: Mixed, row: Number, prop: String, source: String)
```

do the formatting of the cell

Also, in your example, you are setting the renderer, but is the cell actually being rendered? Do you need to re-render?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your renderer is for TextCell.. it would work for only text cell, check that error Renderer should work for TextCell or NumericCell